В ответе нет объекта, который находится в области bbox
Уважаемые Гуру!
Запрос должен вернуть все объекты с geocode=Машезеро в республике Карелия. Если bbox не указывать то в ответе содержится Деревня Машезеро Прионежский район Нововилговское поселение.
Чтоб ограничить поиск , указывают bbox, который заведомо содержит всю территорию республики

https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=...26d&format=json&bbox=29.306117,60.679619~37.946517,66.668643&rspn=1&geocode=Машезеро

Однако нужной деревни в списке нет. В ответе есть деревня с таким же названием в Беломорском районе, а деревня из Прионежского района появляется только в случае , если долготу правого верхнего угла указать скажем 50 или 60 градусов. Хотя координаты деревни
61°37′23″ с. ш. 34°17′53″ в. д.H (Можно посмотреть здесь Машезеро Прионежский район)
В чём может быть дело?
